# Express.JS req.body is logging _locals: [Object: null prototype] {} to the console

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have add-user.ejs file which has a simple form. With the POST method, I am trying to get the data with req.body but when I log it  into the console I get this line:

*_local: [Object: null prototype] {}*

- I tried but did not work

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

**App.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoute');
const adminData = require('./routes/addUser');

app.set('views','views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: false
}));



app.use('/admin',adminData.routes);
app.use(userRoutes);

app.listen(3000);
```

**add-user.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form_div">
        <form method="POST" action="/admin/add-user">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Add username">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**addUser.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/add-user',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('add-user.ejs',users);
})

//Redirect
const users = [];

router.post('/add-user',(req,res)=>{
    users.push({title:req.body.name});
    console.log(users);
    res.redirect('/');
})

exports.routes = router;
exports.users = users;
```

Edit:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "assignment4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah by default they are logged like that, what you can do is to stringify the object:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));`
I use the last two params to have pretty print of the object, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the built in json handler in express. This can be done by implementing this line of code in app.js:

```
app.use([express.json(), express.urlencoded()])
```

You can also add other built in functions to the array, such as express.text() for handling bodies as plain text.

Comment: body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option, seems like this is deprecated

Comment: Oh yeah it should be `app.use([express.json(), express.urlencoded({ extended: true })])`, my bad.

Comment: It's not fixing the issue :)